# Spring aspect around for @Service annotation is not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aspects

I want to use aspect method depending on specific annotation. In my scenario when I mark up my business class with `@Service` annotation it is not working, but when I change it to component it starts to work.

Here is sample:

```
  My Aspect class...
        @Aspect
        @Component
        public class MyAspect
        {
        ....
            @Around(value="@annotation(com.myannoation.annotation.MyAnnotate)")
            public Object MyMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Exception {
                return ......
            }
    .......

    @Component-->it is work
    @Service -->it is not working
    @Path("api/myapisample")
    public class myapicontroller {


        @POST
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response confirm(MyRequest request)
        {

.....
```

Comment: Works for me (Spring Boot 2.1.4). What package is the @Service annotation from?

Comment: 2.1.3.RELEASE  my version is this.

Comment: @Bilgehan, were you able to get this resolved? I'm seeing the same issue. My Aspect works on methods in my controllers, but not on methods in my services.

Comment: FYI, turns out for me seems to have been that my method was running via a scheduler (Quartz), which for some reason that I'm as yet unclear on seems to ignore the custom aspect with which I had annotated the method.

Comment: Mycase not related with quartz, I change service to component